# How to create a popup

Tags: android, popup

How to open a similar popup like the one that appears when you click on a contact icon in contacts? Is Dialog suitable for that? Or maybe PopupWindow?

[image: Android screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It's a quickaction. Check [this link](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PopupWindow is th way to go.